# Codeigniter view is unexpectedly showing all data

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to show only user data in view. In the present case all data is displaying either it is filled by logged in user 1, logged in user 2. Is the problem in this line of controller code or session problem? Problem is that any user can see other user data.

```
$sql="SELECT u.*,f.manu_id,m.journal_id,m.title,j.sub_title,f.created_date,f.final_status
```

This is my User_controller code:

```
public function FinalManuscriptSubmit()
{
    if ($this->Common_model->Is_User_Logged()) 
    {   
        $data=array();
        $joinClause=array();
        $whereClause=array();

        #$session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_logged_in');
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_email');

        $u_id         = $session_data['id'];

        $sql="SELECT u.*,f.manu_id,m.journal_id,m.title,j.sub_title,f.created_date,f.final_status
        FROM user u 
        INNER JOIN final_manuscript f on f.user_id = u.user_id
        INNER JOIN manuscript m on m.manu_id = f.manu_id
        INNER JOIN journal j on j.sub_id = m.journal_id
            ";
        $data['list']=$this->Common_model->get_data_by_query($sql); 
        //print_r($data['list']);exit;
        $this->load->view('user/header');
        $this->load->view('user/showmanu',$data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer');
    }else{
        redirect('user/login');
    }
}
```

This is my view

```
 <table class="table table-hover">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Manuscript ID</th>
                    <th>Journal</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php 
                    if(!empty($list)>0)
                      { 
                        foreach ($list as $row) 
                          {
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->manu_id;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->sub_title;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->title;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->created_date;?></td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="<?php echo site_url('user/removemanuscript/'.base64_encode($row->manu_id)); ?>" title="Soft Delete">Remove
                        </a>
                        <?php if($row->final_status==1){ ?>
                        <span class="label label-primary">Approved</span>
                      <?php }else if($row->final_status==2){ ?>
                        <span class="label label-danger">Disapproved</span>
                      <?php }else{ ?>
                       <span class="label label-warning">Pending</span>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                         } }   
                  ?>
                </table>
```

Comment: you need a where clause in your query...
where id = your loggued user id

Comment: can you write exact query?How I can add in my code.I will be grateful to you?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that, you never set the query to get the logged user. You need a where clause in your query to set that.

```
$sql="SELECT
    u.*, f.manu_id, m.journal_id,
    m.title, j.sub_title, f.created_date, f.final_status
    FROM user u 
    INNER JOIN final_manuscript f on f.user_id = u.user_id
    INNER JOIN manuscript m on m.manu_id = f.manu_id
    INNER JOIN journal j on j.sub_id = m.journal_id
    WHERE u.user_id = :u_id";
```

This way you are getting only the user that matches with your user id in session.

As you can see, I have used a placeholder `:u_id`, into which `$u_id` should be bound, using whatever database driver/library you have. This will prevent a SQL injection vulnerability from emerging.

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

SELECT u.*,f.manu_id,m.journal_id,m.title,j.sub_title,f.created_date,f.final_status FROM user u INNER JOIN final_manuscript f on f.user_id = u.user_id INNER JOIN manuscript m on m.manu_id = f.manu_id INNER JOIN journal j on j.sub_id = m.journal_id WHERE u.user_id =

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: u_id

Comment: there is the problem then, you are not retrieving the id of the loggued user, when you do that, the query will work fine.

Comment: print_r($u_id);exit; this command is giving 7.Can you suggest something?

Comment: I am accepting your answer, with WHERE u.user_id = " .$u_id;

Comment: This answer recommends a query containing a SQL injection vulnerability. Please change it so that it uses a placeholder `?` or `:user_id` and then ping me so that I can remove the downvote. As it stands, this is dangerous advice - always use bound parameters. cc @KumarAjeet

Comment: here is the documentation of what @halfer said in previous comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries

Comment: @halfer That requieres the user to use a PDO connection. Actually I wouldn't even write a query in the controller, but in the model, and there use the Codeigniter query builder

Comment: @AleOtero93: nevertheless, I am sure there is a way you can make this query safe, even if you also need to add a sentence explaining where the query is best added.